# Azure web apps: Warning about an "auto-swap lock file"

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, octopus-deploy, azure-deployment-slots

I'm using Octopus Deploy to deploy a web application to Azure web apps. I'm using the deployment slots with auto-swap feature to warm the app up before making it accessible.

Now Octopus Deploy issues a warning after every deployment:

> An auto-swap lock file from a previous deployment was detected and deleted.

Is this a problem? If not (which I suspect), how can I disable the warning?

Comment: Does that happen regardless of how spaced out deployments are, or only when two deployments are happening within minutes of each other?

Comment: @DavidEbbo I just confirmed this: I created a new deployment, the last one was 20h ago. The warning is still there!

Comment: Could you share the name of your site, directly or indirectly (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? Also, what's the UTC time of one such deployment? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation, this appears to be an Azure bug. We are working on a fix, but for now you can safely ignore the warning.

Comment: What's the status on this? I just set up deployment of an ASP.NET Core Web App from Octopus and I'm getting the same warning.

Comment: @henningst, can you share your site name directly or in-directly https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly, so that i can take a look for you

Comment: It's the two web apps on the same service plan as http://dummy020716.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: @henningst i see 8 sites in total, can you give a bit more hints which two sites ?

Comment: It's the sites in the same resource group as the one mentioned above. The resource group name is sequereme-prod-rg.

Comment: Any update on this? It's been over 10 months now and I'm still getting this warning when deploying through Octopus Deploy

Comment: Same problem here... almost two years later :(

Comment: David Ebbo, still not fixed?

Comment: Still not fixed. I just setup a new Octopus deploy to a staging slot that's set for auto-swap and getting this message in my logs.

Comment: I can also confirm this still isn't fixed. Auto-swap isn't working for my Octopus Deploy deployments.

Comment: I have the same issue (Octopus version 4.1.5) deploying to Azure WebApp 'wa ... nero(Staging)' in Resource Group 'rg- ... ator', using subscription-id 'af7d77 ... d53b45'